# Register as an Apple developer - as a company

Tags: ios, iphone-developer-program, apple-developer

I am developing an app, and I just finished registering my company as an LLC in California.

I have been developing it on my personal mac, but now I want to enroll in the Apple developer program - but as a **company**, not a private developer.

I opened an Apple ID for the company - using the company email. I am getting stuck with the two-factor authentication because all my devices are obviously under my personal Apple ID.

How am I supposed to get around this?

Also, is this the right way? I started out by requesting a DUNS number but they told me to enroll with the Apple Dev program first.

Comment: I don't know if you're doing it the right way, I've never done this before. But, to set up 2FA you can add phone numbers, even if they're on other accounts. You can also make a new login on your computer and sign into the account there.

Comment: @EzekielElin What would be the right way of doing it do you think? Do I need a separate device for my company?

Comment: @EzekielElin Thank you - I'll try the new login see if that does that trick

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375659/2fa-for-multiple-apple-ids-on-same-device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened another user on my iMac and that fixed it. Thanks @EzekielElin